# Slideshow position changes with different computer with different size

Tags: html, css, alignment, positioning

Link: http://danielknightstudiob.com/seniorgallery.html

I am trying to center the slideshow with the header and the nav bar and it works fine on my computer but as soon as I check on a different computer, it starts overlapping the nav bar or moves away from it. In short, I am having positioning issues.

In Css for slideshow I have,

```
.slideshow {display: block;
            position: absolute; left:28%; top:15%;
            z-index: 0;}
```

and in Html I have,

```
dl.image_map {display:block;
              width:1034px;
              height:60px; 
              background:url(http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201306121035353_seniornav.jpg); 
              position:absolute; left:20%;  }
```

Comment: Basically, your complete html structure is not ok... you should wrap slideshow and menu in relatively positioned divs... (margin:o auto will do horizontal centering) - also, don't use image as menu - there are tons of tutorials how to create html/css menu. http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

Answer (score 0):

This is why browser testing is important, right?

You could try changing to position: relative on both .image_map and .slideshow, then adjust your left percentages to achieve your desired layout.  Absolute positioning can interfere with your design's ability to respond appropriately to different browsers.